# onDeviceChange() only works properly in macOS Chrome

Tags: javascript

I want to detect when audio input or output devices changes, figured `onDeviceChange()` would do the trick. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/syh06pxd/) is the fiddle. When I plug in headphones (which have a mic) into the headphone jack - with or without `getUserMedia` permission, which isn't required anyway - this works as expected in macOS Chrome by displaying `device change!` every time. However, it does **not** appear to work the same anywhere else.

- macOS Chrome: Works. Also worth nothing, regardless of permissions (`prompt`, `granted`, `denied`)
- macOS Firefox (with permissions): Fires *exactly* once, despite plugging/unplugging many times
- Windows 10 Chrome: This seems *particularly* bizarre! Doesn't work at all, even with permission
- Windows 10 Firefox: Wasn't able to test, but assuming it will fire once

I've been googling for a while and, as far as I can tell, this should work in all of those cases. Support:

- [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/ondevicechange)
- [Can I use](https://caniuse.com/#search=ondevicechange)
- Firefox bug: [Implement mediaDevices.ondevicechange for Windows](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1300468)
- Firefox bug: [Implement mediaDevices.ondevicechange for Mac OSX](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1286429)

There is a footnote on the first two that says "MediaDevices.ondevicechange is supported only on macOS", but that was in reference to Firefox 51 from 2017. And in any case, doesn't explain why it doesn't work on current macOS Firefox or, somehow, Windows Chrome.

Digging in a bit further, I looked at the `audioinput` devices I was getting from `enumerateDevices()`. With nothing plugged in:

```
Default - Internal Microphone (Built-in)
Internal Microphone (Built-in)
ZoomAudioDevice (Virtual)
```

And after plugging in the headphones with a mic:

```
Default - External Microphone (Built-in)
External Microphone (Built-in)
ZoomAudioDevice (Virtual)
```

Here's an interesting part: The `deviceId` didn't change, even though it's clearly a different device. I thought this might have something to do with it so I tried connecting & disconnecting a Bluetooth speaker (which indeed shows up as a different device), but I got the same exact result: Works on macOS Chrome every time but only the *one time* on macOS Firefox.

Does anyone else experience this? I only have sporadic access to one physical Windows machine. Am I missing something or is this only properly supported in macOS Chrome? Why would that be, and why wouldn't it work the same in Windows? Perhaps it has to do with the headphone jack specifically?

### Update 1

Per Kaiido, here are the before and after screenshots with Audio MIDI Setup.

No inputs:
[image: No inputs]

After plugging in headphones:
[image: After plugging in headphones]

### Update 2

It seems it had to do with my particular headphones, somehow. I tried with other headphones and on macOS Chrome/Firefox and Windows Chrome, it worked as expected. Wasn't able to test on Windows Firefox but that probably works too. What a waste of time!

Answer (score 0):

> with or without `getUserMedia` permission, which isn't required anyway

That's probably where you got confused.

This Permission is required to be able to listen to the devicechange event, **if this device is not the only one of its kind**.
From the [Media Cpature and Streams specs](https://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-main/#mediadevices)

> When new media input and/or output devices of a `MediaDeviceKind` are made available where zero devices of that `MediaDeviceKind` were available before, or the lone input and/or output device of a `MediaDeviceKind` becomes unavailable, the User Agent *MUST* run the following [**device change notification**](https://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-main/#dfn-device-change-notification-steps) steps in browsing contexts for which [device enumeration can proceed](https://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-main/#device-enumeration-can-proceed) is `true` and [device information can be exposed](https://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-main/#device-information-can-be-exposed) is `false`, but in no other contexts:

In other words this means that if the device that is added or removed is or was the only one of its kind, then this event should get fired now, only if the context is secure (https://) and the Permission was **NOT** granted.

I guess the device you did plug in and out was not the only one of its kind, in which case you'd fall on the next paragraph:

> Additionally, when new media input and/or output devices are made available, or any available input and/or output device becomes unavailable, or the system default for camera or microphone changed, the User Agent *MUST* run the [device change notification steps](https://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-main/#dfn-device-change-notification-steps) in browsing contexts for which [device enumeration can proceed](https://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-main/#device-enumeration-can-proceed) is `true` and [device information can be exposed](https://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-main/#device-information-can-be-exposed) is `true`, but in no other contexts.

This means that the event would anyway fire **if the Permission was granted** (and if the context is secure).

Note that the final paragraph makes it that even events that have been blocked before would fire when the Permission is finally granted.

---

Now regarding Firefox in particular, beware that by default they don't persist that  Permission, meaning that when you stop the gUM stream, if the user didn't checked the "*remember this decision*" tick in the prompt, then the Permission would be void again, and the event wouldn't fire, and even if they did checked it, you'd have to make an initial request for it to be active.

Ps: I only have a mac laptop at hand, and can't remove internal devices but I can confirm it works as expected for adding/removing new devices when I give the proper Permissions in Firefox 80

Comment: I appreciate the effort put into this answer! As well as the translation because _wow_ that is tough to parse. So here's the thing I didn't mention: I did try granting permissions first (that's why the button is there) and in Firefox, the behavior is inconsistent. Actually I just figured out what is happening: **only the first device change event fires**. No matter if the headphones are inserted or not when the fiddle page is loaded, unplugging or plugging results in exactly one event. On macOS Chrome, it works not only every time, but regardless of permissions (prompt, granted, denied).

Comment: Re: "the only one of its kind", I updated the post with more detail. In short, I tried with another device, same result. And the jsfiddle is secure, so that's not it. I don't have access to the Windows machine right now, but I'll update the first set of bullets in the post tomorrow once I do.

Comment: Did you check the "remember this decision" checkbox? There is something that could look like a bug in that they will kill MediaStreamTracks of the same kind when a new device is added/removed (they also discard unused tracks of different kinds). You can see in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/94p63kb8/) that the track is killed after plugging / removing a new device. If you didn't checked the checkbox in the prompt, then the Permission would get revoked at the same time.

Comment: This isn't just a Firefox issue, which is the only one that has that checkbox. Also, even when checking it I get the same result. Also just tried getting permissions first in Windows Chrome: nada.

Comment: Just saw that your system reports both devices with the same id, that means the change is made at a lower level than what the browser has access to. From macOs, you can go to Applications/Utilities/Audio MIDI Setup/ to check what's going on. On my macbook pro, I get the event as described (even on safari).

Comment: Just added before/after screenshots to the post. Here's the strange part about all of this to me: it works as expected in macOS Chrome, but not Firefox. So the system setup shouldn't be an issue, right?

Comment: Ah, my fault man. It seems it had to do with those particular headphones, somehow. I tried with others and on macOS Chrome/Firefox and Windows Chrome, it worked as expected. Wasn't able to test on Windows Firefox but even if it doesn't work there (which it probably does), it has 8% desktop market share in the US and dropping, so I'm not too worried about it. I appreciate all your help and sorry for wasting your time!!